# I cannot find a swipe to unlock setting in Settings on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, settings

How do I remove the *swipe to go to unlock* setting in Ubuntu so's I don't have to swipe to unlock?

Comment: hit the ESC key

Comment: I nees to <b><i>remove</i></b> it.